# Wordpress wp-json API - Custom Post Type returns 403

Tags: plugins, json, plugin-json-api, wp-api

I've been trying for a full day to get a really basic install of the WP-API to answer to a custom post type (in this case called 'transactions').

The post type is set up and fully public, and it's existence is acknowledged by querying `example.com/wp-json/posts/types/transactions`.

I'm getting the expected response from `example.com/wp-json/posts?type=page` but a 403 when trying to access `example.com/wp-json/posts?type=transactions`.

I really can't think of anything else to try! If anyone has any advice I'd really appreciate it. I'm running the site on nginx, PHP v5.4 if it makes any difference.

Comment: @cybmeta The question is regarding the WP REST API, a "feature plugin" to bring a JSON-based REST API to WordPress core.

Comment: In version 1.1 of the JSON REST API custom post type endpoints have to be registered manually.  http://wp-api.org/guides/extending.html#registering-your-endpoints


Improving this process is one of the enhancements we are making to the upcoming release of the plugin.

Comment: @RachelBaker many thanks for this! Have seen so much conflicting information with examples that made it look like I was really missing something simple. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.1 of the JSON REST API custom post type endpoints have to be registered manually. See: http://wp-api.org/guides/extending.html#registering-your-endpoints

In version 2.0 we register endpoints for any custom post types registered with the `show_in_rest` property set to `true`.  Documentation on how to do this: http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/#registering-a-custom-post-type-with-rest-api-support